Minimize a focused window by clicking the panel/dock icon a second time?
In Ubuntu 24.04 I have icons for my open windows, along with a few shortcuts, in the panel/dock. If I click one that's minimized it will open in the foreground. Clicking the icon a second time with the intention of minimizing the same, does nothing. Is there a way to make this work?

Yes, if you don't have it, install gnome tweaks, sudo apt install gnome-tweaks then go to Windows and change either Double click or Secondary click to Toggle Maximize. Test which one suits you better.

I had Tweaks installed but didn't find the specific solution there. It only configures Titlebar actions. I've set it for Second-Click Minimized, but that's the same result as clicking the minimize button. It seems it should be trivial to use the icon to minimize.

I've discovered that this command will enable the desired behavior.
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock click-action 'minimize'
